# Mapping Key value pair to javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I wanted to map data from  the service call to java script object for same javascript object will be passed to the chart api

The single data format of the javascript array should be like this

```
var val2 = {
        label: 'Data Seg2',
        data: [[0, 10]]
```

};

it can have multiple data values also like this

```
var val3 = {
        label: 'Data Seg2',
        data: [[0, 10], [1, 20],[2, 30],[3, 40],[4, 50]]
    };
```

Tha main Array looks like this

```
var datatest = [{
            label: 'First Label',
            data: [[0, 30]]
        }, {
            label: 'Second Label',
            data: [[0, 20]]
        }, {
            label: 'Third Label',
            data: [[0, 50]]
        }, {
            label: 'Fourth Label',
            data: [[0, 10]]
        }];
```

Now i have the service all result like this.

```
{"d":"[{\"label\":\"Lable1\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"108859\"}]},{\"label\":\"Lable2\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"20493248.94\"}]},{\"label\":\"Label3\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"1195\"}]}]"}
```

Now i want to map this result to "datatest" format

How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function like this:

```
var serverJSON = {"d":"[{\"label\":\"Lable1\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"108859\"}]},{\"label\":\"Lable2\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"20493248.94\"}]},{\"label\":\"Label3\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"1195\"}]}]"};
var serverData = JSON.parse(serverJSON.d);
var datatest= $.map(serverData, function(arrayItem) {
    return {
        label: arrayItem.label,
        data: $.map(arrayItem.data, function(dataItem) {
            return [[parseFloat(dataItem.Key), parseFloat(dataItem.Value)]];
        })
    };
});
```

Result is :

```
[{"label":"Lable1","data":[[0,108859]]},{"label":"Lable2","data":[[0,20493248.94]]},{"label":"Label3","data":[[0,1195]]}]
```

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/a878ad4v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You data is a little bit strange, anyway...

```
var rawData = {"d":"[{\"label\":\"Lable1\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"108859\"}]},{\"label\":\"Lable2\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"20493248.94\"}]},{\"label\":\"Label3\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"1195\"}]}]"};    
var dataSet = JSON.parse(rawData.d); 

var fn = function(data){ 
    data.data = data.data.map(function(d){
        return [d.Key, d.Value];
    });
    return data;
};

var newSet = dataSet.map(fn); // what you want
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Lable1",
        "data": [
            [
                "0",
                "108859"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Lable2",
        "data": [
            [
                "0",
                "20493248.94"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Label3",
        "data": [
            [
                "0",
                "1195"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

It will do the trick. Not sure if there is other elegant way to do so.

PS: it is recommended to format your json string first via http://jsonformat.com/ or so

Answer (score 0):

with pure JavaScript you can do this:

```
mapthis = {"d":"[{\"label\":\"Lable1\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"108859\"}]},{\"label\":\"Lable2\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"20493248.94\"}, {\"Key\":\"1\",\"Value\":\"1111111.94\"}]},{\"label\":\"Label3\",\"data\":[{\"Key\":\"0\",\"Value\":\"1195\"}]}]"};

var x = eval(mapthis.d);
var newdatatest = [];
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    var datas = [];
    for(var j=0; j<x[i].data.length;j++){
        datas.push([x[i].data[j].Key, x[i].data[j].Value]);
    }
    newdatatest.push( {label:x[i].label, data:datas} );
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newdatatest,null,2));
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Lable1",
    "data": [
      [
        "0",
        "108859"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Lable2",
    "data": [
      [
        "0",
        "20493248.94"
      ],
      [
        "1",
        "1111111.94"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Label3",
    "data": [
      [
        "0",
        "1195"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```